# How to prevent status bar disappearing before UIImagePickerController covers the whole screen?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, uistatusbar

Here's a GIF showing the issue:

[image]

When presenting a `UIImagePickerController` like this:

`self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)`

the status bar disappears before the image picker is full screen.

The issue I have with this is that as the status bar disappears in a cloud of smoke, the navigation bar jumps up occupying the void left by the status bar. When `UIImagePickerController` is dismissed, the status bar shows up in its rightful place.

I'm currently not customizing the status bar in any way, all default.

Is there a way to prevent `UIStatusBar` from disappearing, at the very least until `UIImagePickerController` animation is complete?

Comment: Do you want to show the status bar on the camera screen that's it?

Comment: No, I don't want the status bar when taking a picture. I just want it to stay in place during the presenting animation, instead of disappearing just when the animation starts.

I want the view I have before presenting `UIImagePickerController`to stay exactly the same (my vc with the status bar) and `UIImagePickerController` on top of that.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I understand it now.


That is a default behavior and also it is recommended by the Apple UI Guidelines 


"Consider temporarily hiding the status bar when displaying full-screen media. A status bar can be distracting when users are trying to focus on media. Temporarily hide these elements to provide a more immersive experience. The Photos app, for example, hides the status bar and other interface elements during browsing of full-screen photos."

[1] https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/

Answer (score 1):

If you want your status bar to stay at the top of your screen, you should create a custom window and apply animations manually. This may help:

```
var newWindow = UIWindow()
let newController = viewControllerToPresent()
var animationDuration = 0.4 // or whatever you want.
// setting newController as root of new window.
self.window.rootViewController = newController
self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
self.window.backgroundColor = .clear
self.window.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
self.window.isHidden = false

UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) { 
    self.window.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
}
```